# Create b2c tenant failed from both ARM API and Portal

Tags: azure-resource-manager, azure-rest-api, azure-service-principal, azure-ad-b2c

From our previous ask, we got to know how to create b2c tenant using ARM API. This is the reference: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/activedirectory/b2c-tenants/create?tabs=HTTP#scopes

PUT [https://management.azure.com/subscriptions/{subscriptionId}/resourceGroups/{resourceGroupName}/providers/Microsoft.AzureActiveDirectory/b2cDirectories/{resourceName}?api-version=2021-04-01](https://management.azure.com/subscriptions/%7BsubscriptionId%7D/resourceGroups/%7BresourceGroupName%7D/providers/Microsoft.AzureActiveDirectory/b2cDirectories/%7BresourceName%7D?api-version=2021-04-01)

But when we tried this from our end it's not working. This failed with error `"The subscription is not registered to use namespace 'Microsoft.AzureActiveDirectory' "`

In order to check what's going wrong we tried to create b2c tenant from Portal.  But there is no use, same error:
[Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rIRhV.png)

How to fix this error and where to register namespace in Azure?

Comment: You can register namespace like this: Go to Azure Portal -> Subscriptions -> Your subscription -> Resource providers -> Microsoft.AzureActiveDirectory -> Register

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> This error usually occurs if you have not registered this provider before creating B2C tenant: `Microsoft.AzureActiveDirectory`

You can check whether that provider is **registered** or **not** like this: ***Go to Azure Portal -> Subscriptions -> Your subscription -> Resource providers***

[image]

***I tried to reproduce the same in my environment and got below results:***

After registering the provider, I ran the below **ARM API call** via Postman and got `Status: 202 Accepted` like below:

```json
PUT https://management.azure.com/subscriptions/{subscriptionId}/resourceGroups/{resourceGroupName}/providers/Microsoft.AzureActiveDirectory/b2cDirectories/{b2ctenantdomain}?api-version=2021-04-01

{
  "location": "United States",
  "sku": {
    "name": "Standard",
    "tier": "A0"
  },
  "properties": {
    "createTenantProperties": {
      "displayName": "b2ctenantname",
      "countryCode": "US"
    }
  }
}
```

**Response:**

[image]

To **confirm** that, I checked the same in Portal and **`B2C tenant`** is created successfully like below:

[image]

When I opened **B2C tenant** in new tab, it took me to below screen:

[image]